# Exporting to excel in rails using roo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, export, roo

I'm exporting some data from table to excel. I'm using roo gem. It seems import is working but there is not sufficient documentation in gem's github repo.

I want to know how to use view file to render data and respond with xlsx format using respond_to.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx
end
```

Highly appreciated if anyone can provide examples of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/roo-rb/roo :

> Roo implements **read** access for all common spreadsheet types

for writing you might want to use something like [caxlsx_rails](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails)